# Really struggling with jumping

Tags: python, pygame

I've tried everything to try and make my sprite jump but I've decided to start from scratch and try and find a way to do this again. Any way you guys can help. My collision detection depends on `vspeed` so I dont think I can set my `vspeed` to 0 when I hit my platform. I've been stuck on this for ages. Right now my character just simply moves up and down. A simple jump is all I need. Any help would be appreciated!

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self,x,y,width = 65, height = 35):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.hspeed,self.vspeed = 2,4

    self.images=[]
    r0 = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\i1.png")
    r1 = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\i2.png")
    r2 = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\i3.png")
    r3 = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\i4.png")
    self.hurt = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\Hurt.png")
    self.images.append(r0)
    self.images.append(r1)
    self.images.append(r2)
    self.images.append(r3)

    self.rotatedimages = []
    rr0 = pygame.transform.flip(r0 ,True, False)
    rr1 = pygame.transform.flip(r1 ,True, False)
    rr2 = pygame.transform.flip(r2 ,True, False)
    rr3 = pygame.transform.flip(r3 ,True, False)
    self.rotatedimages.append(rr0)
    self.rotatedimages.append(rr1)
    self.rotatedimages.append(rr2)
    self.rotatedimages.append(rr3)

    self.gravity = 0.5
    self.index = 0
    self.image = self.images[self.index]
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,width,height)

    self.TimeNum=0
    self.TimeTarget=10
    self.Timer = 0
    self.collision = False

def Level1PlatColl(self, BlockListGrass, TrapList, enemygroup, PowerUps):
    PlatformCollision = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, BlockListGrass, False )
    for each_object in PlatformCollision:
        self.collision = True
        if self.collision == True:
            self.OnGround = True
            if self.vspeed > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = each_object.rect.top

            if self.vspeed <0:
                self.rect.top = each_object.rect.bottom

def move(self):

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
       self.rect.move_ip(-self.hspeed,0)

    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
       self.rect.move_ip(self.hspeed,0)

    if key[pygame.K_UP]:
       self.rect.y -= self.vspeed

    if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        self.rect.y += self.vspeed
```

Comment: use `gravity` to change `vspeed` in every frame/loop.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you press `K_UP` you set `vchange = vspeed` (and `self.OnGround = False`)
2. In every frame/loop you use `y -= vchange` to jump
3. In every frame/loop you use `vchange -= gravity` to slow down jump.

First it will move player up, but gravity slow down player and make player moving down.

(when I say "press" I mean the single moment when key change state from `pygame.KEYUP` to `pygame.KEYDOWN` - not when you keep pressed it - so you will have to use `for event in pygame.event.get()` instead of `pygame.key.get_pressed()` or check `onGround` with `K_UP` )

Comment: ok thanks alot i will try it and by every frame/loop do u mean underneath the K_UP if statement?

Comment: By "every frame/loop" I mean every time in `while True` loop ("mainloop"). It has to be done in every loop even if you don't press any key.

Comment: but `vchange = vspeed` (and `self.OnGround = False`) has to be done underneath the K_UP if statement

Comment: ps. maybe this "Platform jumper" source code helps you: http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/show_file.php?file=platform_jumper.py

Comment: Thanks for the help!